# How to Implement web worker for stemkoski example

Tags: javascript, multithreading, three.js, web-worker

Stemkoski made an example which uses a particle system in [Particle Engine](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Particle-Engine.html). I am looking to use the logic for the candle, but will be making multiple candles and the frame rate tends to drop with just the single instance in his example.

Looking online, I came across another example of a particle system, but on a much larger scale by [Ian Webster](http://www.ianww.com/blog/2012/11/04/optimizing-three-dot-js-performance-simulating-tens-of-thousands-of-independent-moving-objects/). One of the things he talks about using is web workers to prevent the UI from locking up and it seems to be the best way to go (from what I can tell).

I have tried breaking down some web worker examples, such as [This](http://people.mozilla.org/~prouget/demos/worker_and_simulatedannealing/index.xhtml), and implementing the logic into the particle engine, but I am not having any luck. Anyone know if this is even the best way to handle a larger load of particles and particle systems? And if so, what would need to be done for this situation?

Comment: Have you tried with the Shader Particle Engine? http://squarefeet.github.io/ShaderParticleEngine/

Comment: @FalkThiele I had never heard of it. I'll look into it right away.

Comment: @FalkThiele Wow this is awesome. This looks like the perfect way to do what I want. Thanks!